# list comprehension code to txt file

Tags: clojure

how to dump to a txt file the execution of the list comprehension?

```
   (for [ nr [1 2 3] letter [:a :b :c]] (str nr letter)); it generates what I need
```

when I am adding the above code into the (spit "test.txt" the_above_code) form, I have found the Lazy sequence name  (clojure.lang.LazySeq@7d534269).

thank you in advance for a hint/URL.
DG

PS I am updating the initial post... is it possible to write each generated code on a different line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following does the trick:

```
(spit "test.txt"
      (with-out-str 
        (pr (for [nr [1 2 3] letter [:a :b :c]]
              (str nr letter)))))
```

`whith-out-str` allows you to get as a string whatever is printed to the standard output and `pr` prints whatever is passed to it in a readable format (i.e. it works with the `read-string` function). With the combination of these two you can get a readable string representation of the lazy sequence written into the file.

**EDIT**

In order to print each *element* of your list comprehension in a different line you have to both `prn`int it to stdout and realize the lazy sequence with `doall` or someting of the sort. Although if you are *only* creating the sequence for printing its elements then a `doseq` is more suitable and idiomatic:

```
(spit "test.txt"
      (with-out-str
        (doseq [nr [1 2 3] letter [:a :b :c]]
          (prn (str nr letter)))))
```

**test.txt**

```
"1:a"
"1:b"
"1:c"
"2:a"
"2:b"
"2:c"
"3:a"
"3:b"
"3:c"
```

Comment: thank you Juan! Is it possible to write each generated code on a different line?

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your expression in `seq`.

```
(spit "test.txt"
    (seq (for [nr [1 2 3]
               letter [:a :b :c]]
           (str nr letter))))
```

To print on separate lines, just `apply str` the expression. You get your number/letter combinations on different lines, but you lose the list representation.

```
(spit "test.txt"
  (apply str
    (for [nr [1 2 3]
          letter [:a :b :c]]
      (str nr letter "\n")))
```

I prefer this method to the with-out-str method. If, for some reason, you wanted to keep the quotation marks around the strings, you could do:

```
(spit "test.txt"
  (apply str
    (for [nr [1 2 3]
          letter [:a :b :c]]
      (str "\"" nr letter "\"\n"))))
```

And if you want to maintain the Clojure-readable data structure while also keeping the readability of new lines:

```
(spit "test.txt"
  (str "("
    (apply str
      (for [nr [1 2 3]
            letter [:a :b :c]]
        (str "\"" nr letter "\"\n")))
    ")"))
```

But at this point it's getting really ugly, and using `with-out-str` is looking pretty good.

Comment: "This converts the lazy sequence to the non-lazy variety." This bit is not true. Calling `seq` on a lazy-sequence will realize the first element/chunk, not the whole thing. Of course, then printing it will realize the rest. What's going on here is that LazySeq does not implement .toString, but ASeq does.

Comment: Huh. Interesting. Thanks! I didn't see "lazy" anywhere in the documentation for 'seq', and given the behavior, I made an assumption. Oops!